# Nginx Upstream Error

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Looking at my plesk panel logs I see a lot of these errors, I took out my domain and added domain.net in this example

```
3747#0: *97365 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/domain.net/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream

3743#0: *97344 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/domain.net/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

From what I can tell this seems not to be the correct path for php-fpm.sock but I have no idea where to edit it. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Plesk Panel 12